# To obtain data from Json

Tags: android, json, arraylist, autocompletetextview

I would like to obtain the countryId, countryName details from the following a Json (Please refer to the screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1tev.png).

Here is my code: http://prntscr.com/76jbm4 
here:
    ArrayList companyName = new ArrayList();
    AutoCompleteTextView country_editText;
This AutoCompleteTextView shows user a list of country names and I would like to obtain the countryId of the country which user selects.

The problem is I couldn't pass a list for a AutoCompleteTextView consisting of both countryId and countryName.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/76jbm4 what is this link for? It's not working with me

Comment: Do you get any error ?

Comment: Instead of passing multiple values pass only CountyList and use indexOf to find id of the list.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/76jbm4 is a screenshot oy my program

Comment: @Muthu, I do have any idea of what indexOf is... Can you please help me explaining it

Comment: you are using arraylist is in it? if so you can find index of array list of selected country and use that id to get the county code from another list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a model class

```
class country{  

private String countryName;  
private String countryPhonecode;  
private int countryId;  
private String countryCode;  

//getters and setters    
}  
List<Country> countryNameList=new ArrayList<Country>();  

for(int i=0;i<yourArray;i++){  
JSONObject json=array.getJSONObject(i);  
country c=new country();  
c.setcountryName(json.getString("countryName"));  
//do same with all parameter  

countryNameList.add(c);    
}  

and Now use indexOf to find id of the list like that.

list.get(position).getCountryId().
```

I hope it will help you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I haven't used indexOf in my experience. Can you please explain me how I can use it

Comment: list.get(position).getCountryId().    here can you please explain how I can get the value for position

Comment: @ParthibanM when you click any Item of list it alway return a position which tells you the index. and with the help of that index you can get country class object.and when you get object,now you cant get country id with the help of getCountryId() method of country class.

Comment: but here in my case, since it is autocompleteTextView the position changes whenever there is a textchange in  the editable text.  Is that not a problem?